# GZip response in API method with .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, api, .net-core

I need to GZip the object returned by a single API method in .NET Core 3.1 without enabling GZip globally.

I do it this way:

```
  [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {

        var data =new  Foo();
        string serializedData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);


        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(serializedData);

        using (var msi = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        using (var mso = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var gs = new GZipStream(mso, CompressionMode.Compress))
            {
                msi.CopyTo(gs);
            }

            Response.Headers.Add("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
            return Ok(mso.ToArray());
        }

    }

public class Foo
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }

}
```

When I test this method  with browser I receive the following error:

```
GET http://localhost:5000/test net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED 200 (OK)
```

It seems the browser cannot decode the GZip content.

What I miss?

Comment: Right now we do not know if the server sent good GZIP or the browser is failing.  So I would use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and check if the sniffer can open the GZIP.

Comment: I've updated the code. Now you can test it.

Comment: Why are you doing this in the first place? Without a `content-disposition` header this can't be saved. `OK` is used to return objects that are serialized eg as JSON, which is definitely *not* what the content type claims. You should use `File()` to return file contents. If you wanted to compress responses you could simply configure ASP.NET Core to do so

Comment: Check [Response compression in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/response-compression?view=aspnetcore-3.1). If you deploy your web app to IIS or Nginx though, their response compression is better

Comment: We cannot GZip all methods due to server performance problems. We are trying to limit GZip a single method that returns a very long text content (5-8 MB).

Comment: What about Brotli, the default? In any case, this is an XY Problem. You had a problem X (how to enable response compression for only the most expensive request) and assumed Y is the solutions - just GZip the content. When that didn't work you asked about that, not the actual problem. BTW you can control the compression level

Comment: Won't `return Ok(mso.ToArray());` just return a JSON representation of a (gzip compressed) byte array?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I had to try a little bit (I don't have that much experience with .Net Core yet). But in the end it was quite simple: :)

```
[HttpGet]
public void Get()
{
  var data = new Foo();
  data.Bar = new string('a', 100000); // dummy content

  string serializedData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);

  var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(serializedData);

  using (var msi = new MemoryStream(bytes))
  using (var mso = new MemoryStream())
  {
    using (var gs = new GZipStream(mso, CompressionMode.Compress))
    {
      msi.CopyTo(gs);
    }

    Response.Headers.Add("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
    Response.Body.WriteAsync(mso.ToArray());
  }

}
```